# Java 17 gradle 7.3.3 Intellij Cannot cast org.gradle.api.file.Directory to java.io.File

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, java-17

I am migrating project from Java 8 to newer version.
I am not using module info.

```
springBootVersion=2.5.7
springCloudVersion=2020.0.5
```

I have an error in Intellij during `build`:

```
Cannot cast object 'property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, undefined)' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar' to class 'java.io.File'
* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cannot cast object 'property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, undefined)' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar' to class 'java.io.File'
```

This issue occurs while using `gradle-7.3.3`,
when changed to `gradle-7.4` issue changes to:

```
Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.
```

On gradle 7.3 the issue is:

```
class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar cannot be cast to class java.io.File (org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @6a4f787b; java.io.File is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar cannot be cast to class java.io.File (org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @6a4f787b; java.io.File is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I think the issue comes from this gradle block (`idea` part) that worked fine before:

```
afterEvaluate {
    contracts {
        baseClassForTests = "(...).contract.ContractBaseSpec"
        basePackageForTests = '(...).contract.tests'
        //targetFramework = TestFramework.SPOCK some other error here
        testMode = 'EXPLICIT'
        baseClassMappings {
            baseClassMapping('.*event.*', '(...).contract.EventContractBaseSpec')
        }
    }

    idea {
        module {
            testSourceDirs += project.contracts.generatedTestSourcesDir
            generatedSourceDirs += project.contracts.generatedTestSourcesDir
        }
    }
}
```

After commenting it - build is ok.

Intellij 2022.1 EAP,
the same in 2021.3.2.

Java version setting in `IntelliJ's` `Project setting` does not make difference, I tried both: `java 11` and `java 17`.

The same with `build tools - gradle JVM` java version setting.

As of https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html
`Java 17` is compatible from `gradle 7.3`.

Running from terminal and from jenkins i see other issue:

```
sdk use java 17.0.2-open

Using java version 17.0.2-open in this shell.

 ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.3
------------------------------------------------------------


 ./gradlew clean build
```

Issue:

```
 > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '(.some-path-here...)/contract/ClientBuilder.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61
```

`Stacktrace:` https://pastebin.pl/view/1449e795

in gradle:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}
```

as for this issue updating groovy from `3.0.3` to `3.0.9` fixes it and shows another issue.
Still why IntelliJ shows different issue?

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the failure and does it happen when running Gradle on the command line rather than via IntelliJ?

Comment: When running from terminal ` ./gradlew build` on current settings there is another issue:
```Spring Cloud Contract Verifier Plugin: Falling back to legacy contracts directory in 'test' source set. Please switch to 'contractTest' source set as this will be removed in a future release.
> Task :application-service-server:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':application-service-server:compileJava'.
> invalid source release: 11
```

fullstack trace on one of versions: https://pastebin.pl/view/04a89d74

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have updated the question to give you proper info what error i have from terminal when i have set java-17 and `Gradle 7.3`.  Then issue is:
`Unsupported class file major version 61`.  `Stacktrace:` https://pastebin.pl/view/1449e795